# WPF Windows Docking that affects other windows in Maximized mode

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, windows-7, wpf-controls

I'm writing a WPF project that is effectively a ticker that runs at the bottom of the screen, above the taskbar. I need the ticker to:

1) Reside directly above the taskbar
2) Stay on top of all other windows
3) To continue to do so if the taskbar is set to auto-hide, without obstructing the taskbar
4) Make it so that other windows, which are maximized, don't occupy the space behind the ticker. So it should behave the same way as the task bar, in that it occupies permanent desktop space, which no other applications can use.

Currently, the previous developer just set the ticker by finding the screen size, and putting at the bottom by getting the screen size minus the ticker height, and setting that value to the Top of the WPF window. But that doesn't work for numbers 3 and 4 above. Number 2 is easy enough, just set TopMost="True"

I've seen some posts about docks and stickiness and huddled masses, but I don't think they're doing exactly what I need. Does anyone know how to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: How do I mark this post as solved or finished? Or should I just delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who cares, it turns out I wasn't searching for the correct terms. What I wanted is called an AppBar. The solution I found is here: stackoverflow.com/questions/75785/… The solution works perfectly.