# C# Window Docking

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm just wondering how do I achieve this kind of window docking.
Our Service Desk is using a legacy application "Outlook Email Tagger" where they can add additional information in the email items.
The application can dock on the top of the window and all the windows behind it will automatically resize their height. I think this was
created using VB 6.0 and I'm about to convert it using C#.net.

So far `this.Dock = DockStyle.Top` doesn't do the trick because it only dock the window on the top of the screen but windows behind it still
in maximize mode.

I have attached the program for you to have a better picture on it.

[EmailToolBar](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60827854/ToolbarDec16%28updated%29.zip)

Thanks

Comment: Referencing an executable file to download as you have is dangerous.

Comment: Your link is dead shall you provide a picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of window is called an ["Application Desktop Toolbar"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144177%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and can be implemented via [P/Invoking to the base APIs](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3728/C-does-Shell-Part):

Duplicates:

- [How do you do AppBar docking (to screen edge, like WinAmp) in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75785/how-do-you-do-appbar-docking-to-screen-edge-like-winamp-in-wpf)
- [How to dock an application in the Windows desktop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792024/how-to-dock-an-application-in-the-windows-desktop?lq=1)
- [Windows API to attach window to the left or to right of desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12406698/windows-api-to-attach-window-to-the-left-or-to-right-of-desktop?lq=1)
- [WPF application that claims desktop real estate similar to windows taskbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804697/wpf-application-that-claims-desktop-real-estate-similar-to-windows-taskbar?lq=1)
- [How to limit bottom window full screen max y position on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402186/how-to-limit-bottom-window-full-screen-max-y-position-on-windows?lq=1)
- [WPF Windows Docking that affects other windows in Maximized mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353577/wpf-windows-docking-that-affects-other-windows-in-maximized-mode?lq=1)
- [C# Desktop App Bar (Somewhat Like a taskbar)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845837/c-sharp-desktop-app-bar-somewhat-like-a-taskbar?lq=1)